# dicom header personal information conversion to a .txt file

Tags: matlab, dicom

I have a series of DICOM Images which I want to anonymize, I found few Matlab codes and some programs which do the job, but none of them export a .txt file of removed personal information. I was wondering if there is a function which can also save removed personal information of a DICOM images in .txt format for features uses. Also, I am trying to create a table which shows the corresponding new images ID to their real name.(subjects real name = personal-information-removed image ID)

Any thoughts?

Thanks for considering my request!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you only want to output to your text file the fields that are *changed* by [anonymization](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/dicomanon.html) (either modified, removed, or added). First, you may want to modify some [`dicomanon`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/dicomanon.html) options to reduce the number of changes, in particular passing the arguments `'WritePrivate', true` to ensure private extensions are kept.

First, you can perform the anonymization, saving structures of pre- and post-anonymization metadata using [`dicominfo`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/dicominfo.html):

```
preAnonData = dicominfo('input_file.dcm');
dicomanon('input_file.dcm', 'output_file.dcm', 'WritePrivate', true);
postAnonData = dicominfo('output_file.dcm');
```

Then you can use [`fieldnames`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fieldnames.html) and [`setdiff`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html) to find fields that are removed or added by anonymization, and add them to the post-anonymization or pre-anonymization data, respectively, with a `nan` value as a place holder:

```
preFields = fieldnames(preAnonData);
postFields = fieldnames(postAnonData);

removedFields = setdiff(preFields, postFields);
for iField = 1:numel(removedFields)
  postAnonData.(removedFields{iField}) = nan;
end

addedFields = setdiff(postFields, preFields);
for iField = 1:numel(addedFields)
  preAnonData.(addedFields{iField}) = nan;
end
```

It will also be helpful to use [`orderfields`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/orderfields.html) so that both data structures have the same ordering for their field names:

```
postAnonData = orderfields(postAnonData, preAnonData);
```

Finally, now that each structure has the same fields in the same order we can use [`struct2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct2cell.html) to convert their field data to a cell array and use [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) and [`isequal`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isequal.html) to find any fields that have been modified by the anonymization:

```
allFields = fieldnames(preAnonData);
preAnonCell = struct2cell(preAnonData);
postAnonCell = struct2cell(postAnonData);
index = ~cellfun(@isequal, preAnonCell, postAnonCell);
modFields = allFields(index);
```

Now you can create a [table](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) of the changes like so:

```
T = table(modFields, preAnonCell(index), postAnonCell(index), ...
          'VariableNames', {'Field', 'PreAnon', 'PostAnon'});
```

And you could use [`writetable`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html) to easily output the table data to a text file:

```
writetable(T, 'anonymized_data.txt');
```

Note, however, that if any of the fields in the table contain vectors or structures of data, the formatting of your output file may look a little funky (i.e. lots of columns, most of them empty, except for those few fields).

Comment: Thank you so much for detailing these requirements.

I ran your code but I got this error:

"Error using cellfun
All of the input arguments must be
of the same size and shape.
Previous inputs had size 155 in
dimension 1. Input #3 has size 106"

It seems logical since some parts of the vector has been removed, any idea?

Comment: @mohammadreza: I added a note to my answer to explain the problem and how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your response,
I changed 'WritePrivate' form 'false' to 'true', but I got the same error with small change:


Error using cellfun
All of the input arguments must be
of the same size and shape.
Previous inputs had size 155 in
dimension 1. Input #3 has size
147.

Error in Untitled22 (line 10)
index = ~cellfun(@isequal,
preAnonCell, postAnonCell);

Comment: I added your "note script", but I got this error:
Argument to dynamic structure
reference must evaluate to a valid
field name.

Error in Untitled22 (line 8)
  postAnonData.(missingFields(iField))
  = nan;  % Or some other
  placeholder to

Comment: @mohammadreza: There was a typo (curly braces we're needed). It should work now.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, but same error occurred. This time, the matrix demnsions are much closer but still not the same :

Error using cellfun
All of the input arguments must be
of the same size and shape.
Previous inputs had size 155 in
dimension 1. Input #3 has size
157.

Error in Untitled22 (line 17)
index = ~cellfun(@isequal,
preAnonCell, postAnonCell);

Comment: @mohammadreza: Okay, I modified my answer quite a bit. It turns out `dicomanon` sometimes *adds* fields, which I didn't expect. The new general approach above *should* work for you now.

Comment: Thank you so much, the error has been removed, now the only problem is in creating table, i got this error:
Undefined function 'table' for input
arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in Untitled22 (line 28)
T = table(modFields,
preAnonCell(index),
postAnonCell(index), ...

Comment: @mohammadreza: Well, it sounds like you're probably using an older version of MATLAB, pre R2013b, when `table` was introduced. I don't know offhand what earlier options there were.

Comment: Thank you so much for you support!
I will install a new version of matlab and report the result.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to store the tags before and after anonymisation and use these to write your text file. In Matlab, `dicominfo()` will read the tags into a structure:

```
% Get tags before anonymization
tags_before = dicominfo(file_in);

% Anoymize
dicomanon(file_in, file_out); % Need to set tags values where required

% Get tags after anonymization
tags_after = dicominfo(file_out);

% Do something with the two structures
disp(['Patient ID:', tags_before.PatientID ' -> ' tags_after.PatientID]);
disp(['Date of Birth:', tags_before.PatientBirthDate ' -> ' tags_after.PatientBirthDate]);
disp(['Family Name:', tags_before.PatientName.FamilyName ' -> ' tags_after.PatientName.FamilyName]);
```

You can then write out the before/after fields into a text file. You'd need to modify `dicomanon()` to choose your own values for the removed fields, since by default they are set to empty.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i got this error:

Error using exist
The first input to exist must be a
string.

Error in dicom_get_msg (line 18)
if (exist(file.Filename) ~= 2)

Error in dicominfo>getFileDetails
(line 387)
    file = dicom_get_msg(file);

Error in dicominfo (line 36)
    fileDetails =
    getFileDetails(filename);

Error in Untitled2 (line 2)
tags_before = dicominfo(660);

Comment: The argument `file_in` to `dicominfo(file_in)` needs to be a string, which is the path and filename of the DICOM file. The error suggests you are passing in a number, file handle or something else.